# How to fix: "Unknow command: manage.py" in a Django project in PyCharm (newbie)

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm totally new to Django, just learned a bit Python for science analysis. I use PyCharm as IDE wanted to made the django "tutorial" from the PyCharm website (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html). I struggle quite early at the point "Launching Django Server". So, I can open the new command line with Ctrl+Alt+R, but when I enter "manage.py" as described in the tutorial I get the error "Unknown command: manage.py Type'manage.py help' for usage". If I type 'manage.py help' the same error occurs. Since PyCharm creates the files, the code itself should be functional since I didn't changed a single line.
The versions are: PyCharm 2019.1.3 (Professional); Python: 3.7; Django: 2.2.3

I tried to run PyCharm as administrator. Since I'm totally new to Django I also have no idea what else I should try. A google search showed just findings not comparable to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is telling you that PyCharm is already supplying "manage.py" for you, so you are effectively doing "manage.py manage.py". Put in the command you want to run, on its own.

Comment: Thanks a lot, then I was to stupid to understand the tutorial correctly, but you are right, every other command works, like migrate etc.